# Sampling a subset from unlabeled training set

Tags: machine-learning

What is a recommended method to sample a subset of 40 out of 400 unlabeled images, so that these 40 images will be informative and will provide a good representation of the 400 images space. These 30 images will be used as part of unsupervised training (CycleGAN).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is impossible to answer because you do not specify your criterion for image variability, which could be based on the distance in color space or the number of angels depicted in the image ;-)

Let us thus assume that you have some criterion that measures the distance between images. Then you can compute the distance matrix of all your images and do a *k-medoids* clustering with $k=40$ (the desired size of your subset). The images corresponding to the cluster centers of the computed $k$ clusters should be something along the lines you are looking for, i.e., represent a wide variability. Beware however, that each image might "represent" a different number of images (the size of the corresponding cluster).